# MySQL SUM with GROUP BY producing long decimals

Tags: mysql, math, group-by, sum

So, I have no idea why this is happing. I know I can fix it with rounding, but I'd like to know why I even need to. I am selecting a set of double, grouping them by a common factor, and applying SUM to them. In the results, I get very long decimals, at times a rounded repeating. An example might be 185708.90000000002 or 199959.34999999998.

I have no idea how this could happen. The most precise my numbers are before summing is 10^2. It's important to note also, that this does not happen all the time, just occasionally. In most cases the numbers look correct.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question, thanks to a comment. Floats and Doubles are not stored as *exact* numbers internally. Converting the columns to Decimal solves most issues.